# Error when running BetterBusBuffers "Count Trips on Lines" tool in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, general-transit-feed-specification, transit

After running the "Count Trips on Lines" tool of the [BetterBusBuffers](https://github.com/Esri/public-transit-tools/blob/master/better-bus-buffers/UsersGuide.md#PreprocessGTFS) toolbox, I encounter the following error after running step 2, "[count trips on lines](https://github.com/Esri/public-transit-tools/blob/master/better-bus-buffers/UsersGuide.md#CountTripsOnLines):"

**"There is no transit service during this time window. No service_ids cover the weekday or specific date you have selected."**

On further inspection of the GTFS package's calendar.txt file, I find that every one of the [day of week] fields is entered as zero, which seems unusual. Original GTFS package is [here](https://www.vrn.de/service/entwickler/gtfs/index.html).

Screenshot is below:

[image]

Any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Answer from the developer of the BetterBusBuffers tool, Melinda Morang:

> It looks like this agency just decided to explicitly turn on service
> using the calendar_dates.txt file for specific dates rather than
> including a regular service defined in calendar.txt.  To successfully
> run the BetterBusBuffers tools, you should use a specific YYYYMMDD
> date for the input date instead of a weekday.

Choosing a specific date instead of a generic weekday solved this problem.